# Vídeo Cross-browser

Tags: html5, css3

Preciso usar um vídeo e ele tem que ser *cross-browser*. Ele funciona no Google Chrome, Opera e no Mozila, porem ele falha ao ser exibido no Safari. Segue meu código:

segue o código html:

```
        <div id="video">
            <video id="Video1" width="100%" height="100%" loop>
                <source src="video/League-warrios.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>
```

Comment: Pode ser os codecs instalados em seu computador? É um Mac ou Windows?

Comment: Não há nada de errado no seu código. O console do navegador diz algo? Verifique se seu servidor suporta requisições `byte-range`. O Safari exige este suporte (ou pelo menos exigia).

Comment: eu uso windows e assim so estou com um video com formato mp4 seria isso o problema ??? existe algum conversor de video para outros formats como ogg por exemplo

Comment: O Safari suporta MP4 em todas as plataformas. Vale lembrar, que no Windows o Safari não existe mais. Para converter o video para `webm` ou `ogg` eu gosto do `Ultimate Video Converter`, que é nada além de um frontend para o `ffmpeg`. Pode ser que recodificando o arquivo para outro formato o problema se resolva pois o Safari se comporta de outra maneira com outros formatos de video (na questão das requisições `byte-range` - implementar este suporte é simples, inclusive).